# Maven Surefire Run Tests Command Line String Limitation (-Dtest=x.y.z#abc)

Tags: maven, jenkins, cmd, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Maven Surefire to run a subset of my test cases via Jenkins on a Windows Server.

To specify the test cases to be run, I execute:

```
mvn surefire:test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=x.y.z#a,x.y.z#b
```

The problem is that on Windows (CMD.exe) there is a [Command Line String Limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) which does not allow for a very long list of tests to be executed (limit 8191 characters).

Does anybody have an idea whether I can maybe use a file as an input for the `-Dtest` parameter (i.e. `-Dtest=testcases.txt`) or any other ideas to solve this problem?

I know I could switch to Groovy scripts in the Jenkins rather than CMD.exe, but I want to avoid that.

**UPDATE [21st Jan 2020]**

Two things I must clarfiy:

1. I'm selecting the test cases dynamically in a Maven multi-module project, which means adjusting the `pom.xml` is generally an option, but I wanted to avoid it.
2. I already tried calling the command from a Python script rather than directly calling it in Window's `cmd.exe`:

```py
import subprocess

command = 'mvn surefire:test -Dtest={} -DfailIfNoTests=false'.format(tests)
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

This doesn't work either, maybe Powershell is an option as @mark-bramnik suggested?

**UPDATE [17th Feb 2020]**

Powershell and/or `.bat` do not work either, nor does running it inside a `.sh` script from the Windows Git bash work.
When running it via the `.sh` script, I get an error related to the JDK:

```
/c/maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn: line 191: /c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11/bin/java: Argument list too long
/c/maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn: line 191: /c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11/bin/java: No error
```

Apparently, the limit to command length is inherently present on the Windows OS.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you call the `test` goal of surefire instead of using the lifecycle?

Comment: There are multiple executions of the surefire plugin configured in the `pom.xml`, that's why I explicitly call the default test phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using Maven Surefire's option `-Dsurefire.includesFile` which can apparently be used similarly to `-Dtest`, except that you can provide a file with the test names.

Comment: Can you please provide more info about that way?
I'm trying to use `-Dsurefire.includesFile`, but it still running all the tests.
Maybe it is wrong format, or maybe it is because the `pom.xml` includes `<includes>**/*.java<includes>`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the list of tests to be run right in the pom.xml of the module you run.

If you want this list to be loaded only from jenkins, create a special maven profile (again, inside the same pom xml) and create a configuration with surefire plugin configuration inside that profile.

Another way is putting the line that you run into some sort of shell script (in windows world it would be power shell something I guess).

Other than that, `-Dtest` cannot be accept the file in the current surefire implementation as far as I know, so If you don't want to extend the surefire plugin (in which I doubt :) ) you should probably use one of the aforementioned methods

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I considered the `pom.xml` solution already, but as I select these tests dynamically, based on static analysis of the changes and the previous test runs, I would always have to override the specific part of the `pom.xml`.

I'm not familiar with the Windows world of scripting either...But I'll try to find a way to put it into a shell script and execute that from my cmd.exe script (which I'm forced to used by the jenkins admins). Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question to also clarify what I've tried already.

Comment: Probably you can just use a *.bat file with a single line that runs maven test

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as the limit is also prevalent in *.bat files (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217134/file-size-and-line-length-limits-for-windows-batch-files).